# How can I get each of my modals to show correctly?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, event-listener

I know this code won't work in the current state because it will just select the first `modal` class. I have tried many variations of using `querySelectorAll` and `forEach` loops in the functions and event listeners but I can't seem to get it right.

How can I convert the current code to work with the different project card modals?

```js
// Project card modals

const modal = document.querySelector('.modal')
const trigger = document.querySelector('.trigger')
const closeButton = document.querySelector('.close-button')
const body = document.querySelector('body')

function toggleModal() {
  modal.classList.toggle('show-modal')
  showModal()
}

function windowOnClick(event) {
  if (this.event.target === modal) {
    toggleModal()
    showModal()
  }
}

trigger.addEventListener('click', toggleModal)
closeButton.addEventListener('click', toggleModal)
window.addEventListener('click', windowOnClick)

// Disable body scroll with modal open

const showModal = function (e) {
  if (modal.classList.contains('show-modal')) {
    // Disable scroll
    body.style.overflow = 'hidden'
  } else {
    // Enable scroll
    body.style.overflow = 'auto'
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="projects-container">
  <div class="projects-grid">
    <div class="project-cell">
      <div class="project-tile trigger">
        <img Card Image />
      </div>
      <div class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="close-button">&times;</div>
          Modal Content
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(68, 71, 90, 0.8);
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px) saturate(180%);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: visibility 0s linear 0.25s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
  z-index: 5;
}

.modal-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: rgb(40, 42, 54, 0.8);
  border-radius: 5px;
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px) saturate(180%);
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px var(--dracula-background);
}

.close-button {
  width: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 500;
  background-color: rgba(255, 85, 85, 0.7);
  cursor: url('../assets/images/icons/cursor-hand-white.png'), auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: ease all 0.1s;
}

.show-modal {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: visibility 0s linear 0s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can definitely refactor this, but I was able to get it working by using the IDs. I also had to switch the `querySelectorAll` to `getElementsByClassName` because `querySelectorAll` will return a static collection, while `getElementsByClassName` returns a live collection.

```js
// Project card modals

const body = document.querySelector('body')
const modal = document.getElementsByClassName('modal')
const trigger = document.getElementsByClassName('trigger')
const closeButton = document.getElementsByClassName('close-button')

// When the user clicks the project image, open the modal

trigger[0].onclick = function () {
  modal[0].classList.toggle('show-modal')
  if (modal[0].classList.contains('show-modal')) {
    // Disable scroll
    body.style.overflow = 'hidden'
  } else {
    // Enable scroll
    body.style.overflow = 'auto'
  }
}

trigger[1].onclick = function () {
  modal[1].classList.toggle('show-modal')
  if (modal[1].classList.contains('show-modal')) {
    // Disable scroll
    body.style.overflow = 'hidden'
  } else {
    // Enable scroll
    body.style.overflow = 'auto'
  }
}

trigger[2].onclick = function () {
  modal[2].classList.toggle('show-modal')
  if (modal[2].classList.contains('show-modal')) {
    // Disable scroll
    body.style.overflow = 'hidden'
  } else {
    // Enable scroll
    body.style.overflow = 'auto'
  }
}

trigger[3].onclick = function () {
  modal[3].classList.toggle('show-modal')
  if (modal[3].classList.contains('show-modal')) {
    // Disable scroll
    body.style.overflow = 'hidden'
  } else {
    // Enable scroll
    body.style.overflow = 'auto'
  }
}

// When the user clicks on (x), close the modal

closeButton[0].onclick = function () {
  modal[0].classList.toggle('show-modal')
  body.style.overflow = 'auto'
}

closeButton[1].onclick = function () {
  modal[1].classList.toggle('show-modal')
  body.style.overflow = 'auto'
}

closeButton[2].onclick = function () {
  modal[2].classList.toggle('show-modal')
  body.style.overflow = 'auto'
}

closeButton[3].onclick = function () {
  modal[3].classList.toggle('show-modal')
  body.style.overflow = 'auto'
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it

window.onclick = function (event) {
  if (event.target == modal[0]) {
    modal[0].classList.toggle('show-modal')
    body.style.overflow = 'auto'
  }
  if (event.target == modal[1]) {
    modal[1].classList.toggle('show-modal')
    body.style.overflow = 'auto'
  }
  if (event.target == modal[2]) {
    modal[2].classList.toggle('show-modal')
    body.style.overflow = 'auto'
  }
  if (event.target == modal[3]) {
    modal[3].classList.toggle('show-modal')
    body.style.overflow = 'auto'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use unique `id` attributes on your modal elements to differentiate them, and then use data attributes to target modals.

```js
// Project card modals
const body = document.querySelector('body')

function toggleModal(modal) {
  modal.classList.toggle('show-modal')
  showModal(modal)
}

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('modal')) {
    toggleModal(event.target)
    showModal(event.target)
  } else if (event.target.classList.contains('trigger')) {
    toggleModal(document.getElementById(event.target.getAttribute('data-target')))
  } else if (event.target.classList.contains('close-button')) {
    toggleModal(document.getElementById(event.target.getAttribute('data-target')))
  }
})

// Disable body scroll with modal open

const showModal = function(modal) {
  if (modal.classList.contains('show-modal')) {
    // Disable scroll
    body.style.overflow = 'hidden'
  } else {
    // Enable scroll
    body.style.overflow = 'auto'
  }
}
```

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(68, 71, 90, 0.8);
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px) saturate(180%);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: visibility 0s linear 0.25s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
  z-index: 5;
}

.modal-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: rgb(40, 42, 54, 0.8);
  border-radius: 5px;
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px) saturate(180%);
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px var(--dracula-background);
}

.close-button {
  width: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 500;
  background-color: rgba(255, 85, 85, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: ease all 0.1s;
}

.show-modal {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: visibility 0s linear 0s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
}
```

```html
<div class="projects-container">
  <div class="projects-grid">
  
    <div class="project-cell">
      <div class="project-tile trigger" data-target="modal1">
        <img Card Image /> trigger1
      </div>
      <div class="modal" id="modal1">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="close-button" data-target="modal1">&times;</div>
          Modal Content 1
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="project-cell">
      <div class="project-tile trigger" data-target="modal2">
        <img Card Image /> trigger2
      </div>
      <div class="modal" id="modal2">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="close-button" data-target="modal2">&times;</div>
          Modal Content 2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="project-cell">
      <div class="project-tile trigger" data-target="modal3">
        <img Card Image /> trigger3
      </div>
      <div class="modal" id="modal3">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="close-button" data-target="modal3">&times;</div>
          Modal Content 3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated my question so you can see the HTML and CSS I'm using. Haven't gotten it to work yet, but I can see where you are going with that though.

Comment: @Steve I update my code to reflect your markup and styles.

Comment: Thanks for the update, that is what I was trying last night but nothing happens when I click on the trigger.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction with the IDs, I was able to get it to work with getElmentsById.